# Как выполнить функцию только при клике по однотипным элементам?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два списка элементов
в одни красиво отражаются на экране, а другие - скрытый список содержащий в себе большое количество текстовой информации, связаны между собой с помощью атрибута `data`

Написал вот так и ЭТО даже работает. Но по-моему тут

```
idpolygon = e.target.attributes[1].value;

if (idpolygon) {
```

я нагородил какую то хрень, подскажите как написать более красиво.

```js
$('body').click(function(e) {
  var div = $('.str');
  if (!div.is(e.target)) {
    $('.curentwindow').fadeOut(250);
    $('e.target').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.curentwindow').fadeIn(250);
    idpolygon = e.target.attributes['data-sity'].value;
    $('e.target').addClass('active');
    if (idpolygon) {
      curent_obgeqts = $('.hidden[data-sity="' + idpolygon + '"]').text();
      $('.curentwindow').html(curent_obgeqts);

    }

  }

});
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

.str {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.curentwindow {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #ddd;
  clear: both;
}

.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str" data-sity="orb"></div>
<div class="str" data-sity="kursk"></div>
<div class="str" data-sity="nn"></div>
<div class="str" data-sity="smr"></div>
<div class="str" data-sity="nsk"></div>
<div class="str" data-sity="spb"></div>
<div class="str" data-sity="kaz"></div>

<div class="list">

  <div class="hidden" data-sity="orb">Оренбург</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-sity="kursk">Курск</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-sity="nn">Нижний-Новгород</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-sity="smr">Самара</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-sity="nsk">Новосибирск</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-sity="spb">Санкт-Петербург</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-sity="kaz">Казань</div>

</div>
<div class="curentwindow"></div>
```

так же почему-то не работает добавление класса

Comment: зачем брать атрибут по номеру? берите по имени. Ну и, конечно, city, а не sity)))

Comment: @yolosora исправил, спасибо. Но дополнил, почему то не работает, добавление класса.

Comment: `$(e.target)` здесь кавычки не нужны. ну и удаление класса active еще надо будет дописать, а то активные элементы накапливаются

Comment: @yolosora про удаление допишу, это я себя проверял)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let curentwindow = $('#curentwindow');

$('.str').click(function() {
  let i = $(this).data('city');
  curentwindow.html($('.hddn').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('city') == i
  }).html());
});
```

```css
.str {
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#curentwindow {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #ddd;
  clear: both;
}

.hddn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str" data-city="orb"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="kursk"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="nn"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="smr"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="nsk"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="spb"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="kaz"></div>

<div class="list">
  <div class="hddn" data-city="orb">Оренбург</div>
  <div class="hddn" data-city="kursk">Курск</div>
  <div class="hddn" data-city="nn">Нижний-Новгород</div>
  <div class="hddn" data-city="smr">Самара</div>
  <div class="hddn" data-city="nsk">Новосибирск</div>
  <div class="hddn" data-city="spb">Санкт-Петербург</div>
  <div class="hddn" data-city="kaz">Казань</div>
</div>
<div id="curentwindow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С удалением класса `active` и поиском по имени атрибута.

```js
$('body').click(function(e) {
  var div = $('.str');
  if (!div.is(e.target)) {
    $('.curentwindow').fadeOut(250);
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.curentwindow').fadeIn(250);
    idpolygon = e.target.attributes['data-city'].value;
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).addClass('active');
    if (idpolygon) {
      curent_obgeqts = $('.hidden[data-city="' + idpolygon + '"]').text();
      $('.curentwindow').html(curent_obgeqts);

    }

  }

});
```

```css
.list {
  display: none;
}

.str {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #787878;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.curentwindow {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #ddd;
  clear: both;
}

.list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="str" data-city="orb"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="kursk"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="nn"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="smr"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="nsk"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="spb"></div>
<div class="str" data-city="kaz"></div>

<div class="list">

  <div class="hidden" data-city="orb">Оренбург</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-city="kursk">Курск</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-city="nn">Нижний-Новгород</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-city="smr">Самара</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-city="nsk">Новосибирск</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-city="spb">Санкт-Петербург</div>
  <div class="hidden" data-city="kaz">Казань</div>

</div>
<div class="curentwindow"></div>
```